# Failing to return a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

HPP:

```
class Camera {
public:
    Camera(float FOV, float nearPlane, float farPlane);

    std::unique_ptr<glm::mat4x4> getProjectionMatrix();

private:
    std::unique_ptr<glm::mat4x4> projectionMatrix;
};
```

CPP:

```
Camera::Camera(float FOV, float nearPlane, float farPlane) {

    float aspectRatio = DisplayManager::displayWidth / DisplayManager::displayHeight;

    projectionMatrix = std::make_unique<glm::mat4x4>();
    *projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(FOV, aspectRatio, nearPlane, farPlane);
}

std::unique_ptr<glm::mat4x4> Camera::getProjectionMatrix() {
    //std::unique_ptr<glm::mat4x4> projectionMatrix = std::make_unique<glm::mat4x4>();
    //*projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(90.0f, 1.333f, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    return std::move(projectionMatrix);
}
```

Look at the two commented lines. The program will compile whether they are commented out or not, but if they are, the data will be corrupted.

How can I write a getter that returns a unique_ptr that is a private member of the class? How do I set the unique_ptr properly in the constructor?

Comment: Why do you want to return a `unique_ptr` what will it be used for?

Comment: What are you doing with that projection matrix? It seems to me like you'd be fine with returning an observer pointer, instead of rendering it into assign-only state

Comment: Observer pointer is fine as well. I need to pass the matrix to the renderer so it can load it into a shader.

Comment: Then just return `glm::mat4x4*` (or a pointer to const one). When returning unique_ptr by value, you're making the "original" empty (it wouldn't be very unique otherwise)

Comment: You want to access the matrix from another object but do you want to remove the matrix from the `Camera`? I suspect you should be returning a *raw pointer* if you know it won't be used after the `Camera` goes out of scope.Or even a reference to the matrix.

Comment: Why are you using allocated memory for these things at all?

Comment: How can use the object outside it's class if it's not allocated?

Comment: You could just declare `glm::mat4x4 projectionMatrix;` as a member variable and forget about pointers.

Comment: Then: `glm::mat4x4& getProjectionMatrix() { /*...*/ }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a much better idea: stop needlessly allocating memory. Have `Camera` store a `glm::mat4x4` directly, not as a `unique_ptr`. C++ is not Java; you don't have to allocate everything with `new`. All your code becomes much simpler:

```
Camera::Camera(float FOV, float nearPlane, float farPlane)
    : projectionMatrix(glm::perspective(FOV, (DisplayManager::displayWidth / DisplayManager::displayHeight), nearPlane, farPlane))
{
}

glm::mat4x4 &Camera::getProjectionMatrix() { return projectionMatrix; }
```

However, if you absolutely have to use a `unique_ptr` in `Camera`, then you should return a reference, not a smart pointer:

```
glm::mat4x4 &Camera::getProjectionMatrix() { return *projectionMatrix; }
```